# Making coloured Ascii text with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, ascii-art, colorama

I'm trying to make a title with coloured ascii for my code, which pops up when launching the code. I already know how to make ascii text but not coloured.

This is what I've been able to make, but now I want to have it in magenta.

```
result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("By Gxzs", font = "slant" )
print(result)
```

[image: Ascii]

I've already tried making it myself using colorama and termcolor, but I get a weird output :

```
title = pyfiglet.figlet_format(colored("By  Gxzs", color = "magenta"))
print(title)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `colored()` is going to return ASCII escape codes surrounding your input to dictate color changes. You see them in your mangled output with "By Gxzs" in the middle. You want to pass the output of `figet_format()` into `colored()` not the other way around (I think).

Answer (score 3):

A high-level library for "rich" text in the terminal is, well, [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich). The [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama) library that you mentioned is one of its dependencies.

To display the title in magenta, you would do this:

```py
import pyfiglet
from rich import print

title = pyfiglet.figlet_format('By Gxzs', font='slant')
print(f'[magenta]{title}[/magenta]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
import pyfiglet as pyfiglet

def to_color(string, color):
    color_code = {'blue': '\033[34m',
                    'yellow': '\033[33m',
                    'green': '\033[32m',
                    'red': '\033[31m'
                    }
    return color_code[color] + str(string) + '\033[0m'

result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("By Gxzs", font = "slant" )

print(to_color(result,'blue'))
```

For more info information about ANSI Scape Codes and Color Codes [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
af = 132
color = subprocess.run(['tput', 'setaf', f'{af}'], capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf-8')
sgr0 = subprocess.run(['tput', 'sgr0'], capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(f'{color}HELLO{sgr0}')
```

the values for the color (foreground in this case) can be seen using https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4055d6df5b6e4ea87c5a72dc2d604193